# Confused by Deutsche Bahn Legoland ticket and bus

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

According to [LegoLand Getting here page](https://www.legoland.de/en/plan-your-visit/plan-your-visit/getting-here/), the bus ticket is included in the train ticket if I select **LEGOLAND Park or LEGOLAND Feriendorf** as a destination. I booked the following ticket on bahn.de (the screenshot is from the confirmation pdf):

[image]

[image]

I'm confused, why does the comment say that the ticket isn't valid for the bus 818? I'm also confused, why are they requiring me to take a train from Günzburg to Kleinkötz? The bus 818 operates between Günzburg railway station and LEGOLAND so I would prefer to transfer to the bus directly at Günzburg railway station.

In fact, if I do the same search today, I get the trip that transfers to bus at Günzburg and is also 1 hour shorter:

[image]

As you can see it has the very same trains from Nürnberg to Günzburg.

My questions are:

- Is the bus included in my ticket or not?
- With the ticket that I have, can I take the 818 bus directly at the Günzburg railway station?

Also, when I view my trip details and click "Search for alternative connection" the website shows the above ticket I posted:

[image]

If I 'Select' this alternative, will my existing ticket be changed into the new one? Will I need to make any additional payments for it?

Comment: The LEGO page seems to suggest that it is the bus from Guenzburg to LEGOLAND which is included, not from Kleimkoetz to LEGOLAND.

Comment: @mdewey It's the same bus, 818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got too long for a comment, so I'm posting as an answer, even though it's not complete. Any additions are welcome.

There seems to be a bit of confusion with the buses: There is bus 818 which goes from Günzburg to Ichenhausen and back, passing through Kleinkötz and stopping at Legoland on the way. Link to the timetable on the website of VVM (Verkehrsverbund Mittelschwaben): [Linie 818](https://www.vvm-online.de/fileadmin/Fahrplaene/818_Krumbach-Guenzburg.pdf)

And then there is bus 818**A** which only travels between Günzburg station and Legoland. Link to the timetable from the same website: [Linie 818A](https://www.vvm-online.de/fileadmin/Fahrplaene/818A_Legolandshuttle.pdf) - this is also the timetable linked on the Legoland website, so I think that only 818A is included.

Why did this bus not show up on your first search? That's guesswork, maybe the timetable of bus 818A had not yet been entered into the database when you first searched for the trip. Similarly, I cannot tell why bus 818A is also listed as 818 on the DB site.

Is your current ticket valid on bus 818A? I can't tell, but since it's more than three months to go, why not contact Legoland directly and ask?

Is it valid on bus 818? No, that's clearly written on your ticket.

Can you change your ticket? That depends on the type of ticket you booked. If it was a flex ticket, this can be changed for free (you could also cancel and book a new ticket if the new connection is cheaper). A sparpreis should be changeable for a fee (10€ cancellation fee + possible increase in ticket prices), although it would probably be cheaper to just pay extra for the shuttle bus in that case.

My suggestion: If you have a flex ticket, change it to be on the safe side. If not, try to contact Legoland and ask if your "wrong" ticket still allows to use the shuttle bus.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! When I booked the train tickets the LegoLand was not open for 2024 yet and the website linked to 2023 schedule of the bus so that might be one of the reasons it wasn't available to DB.

I have Super Sparpreis ticket and it's a lot cheaper compared to the one that shows up now if I include bus in the search too so I'll just buy bus ticket separately.